# How do I fix a deprecation error for DateTime::year?

Tags: templating, error-message

I am trying to work through deprecation warning. I have not touched Craft in a few months, so I am a bit rusty.

The Deprecation Message is:

> DateTime::year is deprecated. Use the |date('Y') filter instead.

The offending line is:

> {% for year in now.year .. firstEntryEver.postDate.year %}

Here is the context:

```
{% set firstEntryEver = craft.entries.section('posts').orderBy('postDate asc').one() %}
{% for year in now.year .. firstEntryEver.postDate.year %}                        
 <a href="/archives/{{ year }}" class="dropdown-item">
 <i class="material-icons">date_range</i> {{ year }}</a>
 {% endfor %}
```

So, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you fix this:

```
{# Old code #}
{% for year in now.year .. firstEntryEver.postDate.year %}

{# New code #}
{% for year in now.year .. firstEntryEver.postDate |date('Y') %}
```